# touchesBegan not working on UIView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I have created a UIView Programmatically on button click like this

```
self.paintView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height+100)];
[self.paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.paintView];
```

and added that to `navigationController` so i can see my UIView in fullscreen.

But when i tried to detect touch its not working

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch.view==self.paintView && self.paintView ) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9 animations:^{
          [self.sideView setFrame:CGRectMake(-290, 0, self.sideView.frame.size.width, self.sideView.frame.size.height)];
     }];
    }

}
```

This method not at all detecting now.

Comment: that is because you are blocking the parent view with some new view that you have created by code, the touches method belong to the parent view but it can't detect it because the Child view.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below code to add view and check:

```
self.paintView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height+100)];

[self.paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];


[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.paintView];//try this
```

The view created by the generic `UIViewController` fills the window and is in front of your `SubView`. Thus your `SubView` can't receive touches.

`rootViewController.view` be the single top-level view in your window, and add subviews under that and check.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if 'userInteractionEnabled' NOT is enabled on all of the superviews of your view. If any of the superviews have this property set to false, the touch events won't be processed for them or any of their subviews. Check if that can be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

And give your `UIView UserInteractionEnable = YES`

Replace your `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { }` code with mine one you get point.

```
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
 CGPoint pointOnScreen = [touch.view convertPoint:point toView:nil];
 NSLog(@"Point - %f, %f", pointOnScreen.x, pointOnScreen.y);
 NSLog(@"Touch");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make userInteractionEnabled enable on all superviews. If superviews have this property set to false, the touch won't be processed subviews.

You also can use UITapGestureRecognizer.